# Node.js: Better way to process a result composed from asynchronous callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In my node.js app, I have a code snipplet to compose a csv array:

```
function process(alerts, callback) {
    var csvList = [];
    var alertsLength = alerts.length;

    alerts.forEach(function(alert) {
        var name = alert.name;
        var msg = alert.msg;

        // retrieve from database
        // NOTE: the asynchronous part!
        PersonDao.getContact(name, function(error, contact) {
            var csv = "csv:" + contact + "|" + msg;
            csvList.push(csv);

            if (csvList.length == alertsLength) {
                // execute callback with the csvList
                callback(csvList);
            }
        });

    }); // end of alerts loop

}
```

Is there any more elegant (or correct) way to do this?

Comment: No, that's how it's done (apart from that you maybe forgot to pass on the error). Yet there are some libraries that add syntactic sugar by implementing helper functions for using this standard pattern, especially using Deferred objects.

Comment: If you're going to use `async`, [`async.forEachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#foreachseriesarr-iterator-callback) would be a better fit here as you'd lose order with `async.parallel` (if order's important).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use 3rd party libraries for that.

```
var async = require('async');

function process(alerts, callback) {
    //       v--- or async.map(...) to do it in parallel
    async.mapSeries(alerts, function(alert, cb) {
        PersonDao.getContact(alert.name, function(error, contact) {
            cb(error, "csv:" + contact + "|" + alert.msg);
        });
    }, callback);
}
```